# How to copy the responds of the web service request in Katalon and then paste it to the header of another web service request?

Tags: web, request, response, katalon-studio, katalon

i am using Katalon Studio 8.6.8

I am writing Katalon script. In my web testing, i have a step to automate the web service request. Here are the body request:

"client_secret":"....",
"username":"admin",
"password":"admin"

I must take or copy the element response (access token) of this request and copy to the header of next web service request. Is it possible to do it? please help me to make the script. Thank you.